# Import movie file (MPEG/AVI/MOV) into rosbag

Tags: ros, rosbag, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to import an MPEG movie file into a rosbag format?

I have some video recorded off of an HD digital camera that I want to do various processing on (camera calibration and ar_pose), but I'm not sure how to get it into a format that I can use in ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9693/import-movie-file-(mpeg/avi/mov)-into-rosbag/) by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6414 on 2011-04-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karim02](https://answers.ros.org/users/21367/karim02/) on 2015-01-20**:
Hello

I have the same problem, could you help me how to convert a movie file into a rosbag?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll post my code for this tomorrow on my git, I can't push from out of my office. The only thing I still need to add the camera info from xml file and a better way to compute the timestamp, suggestions are welcome.

I've pushed it to : [KU Leuven OpenCV Git](http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/opencv_additions.git)

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-04-13**:
Thanks! This looks like what I needed.  I'll try it out and let you know.

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2013-11-04**:
'I tired your code with some avi files, but with non works, i get:
./bin/video_to_bag v1.bag ~/Desktop/v2.avi
INFO: usage = video_to_bag  
INFO: starting conversion
INFO: got fps of: 25, or 0.040000 incrementation
ERROR: Could not grab a frame, perhaps we're at the end of the movie'
What could be the problem?  I can play the movies with a software.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could not find a "tool" to do this, but you can easily read frames from a video file into opencv:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

And then you can use the image_transport package in ROS to output them onto a topic for processing:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport

Or you could use the python/c++ bagfile interface with opencv to write the frames of the video to the bag file directly.

gl hf

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2011-04-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-04-11**:
Is it fair to upvote you if you are working on the same project as me?